# How to edit a shell argument from the cli

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I need to run an `.sh` file by passing two arguments:

```
$ file.sh arg1 arg2
```

- arg1: `filename.ext`
- arg2: `filename`

Basically I need to strip the extension from the filename, and pass it as a second argument.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Can't you just pass first argument and do this stripping in the script itself?

Comment: @AKS Yes, that would be another possible solution! Could you please help me to understand how to do that in the script itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.sh` file has the following contents:

```
filename="$1"
filename_without_extension="${1%\.*}"
echo "$filename"
echo "$filename_without_extension"
```

Output:

```
$ ./file.sh filename.txt
filename.txt
filename
```

and if you want to strip it while passing the arguments, you need to have a variable declared in the shell like this:

```
$ var="filename.ext"
$ echo ${var%\.*}
filename
$ vim script.sh
$ chmod 755 script.sh 
$ ./script.sh "$var" "${var%\.*}"
filename.ext filename
```

- `${var%\.*}` Remove from $var the matching shortest(at the end of string) part of Pattern `\.*` i.e dot followed by 0 or more characters.

More info on parameter substitution can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Edit:  single `%` ensures the shortest (non-greedy) match from the right is removed hence that would only remove the extension and nothing else from the file-name(even if the file-name contains dots).

Here is a run with those sample values:

Script version:

```
$ cat file.sh 
filename="$1"
filename_without_extension="${1%\.*}"
echo "$filename"
echo "$filename_without_extension"
$ chmod 755 file.sh 
$ ./file.sh file.name.ext
file.name.ext
file.name
```

and the another version where in we pass arguments to script:

```
$ var="file.name.ext"
$ cat script.sh 
echo "$@"
$ chmod 755 script.sh 
$ ./script.sh "${var}" "${var%\.*}"
file.name.ext file.name
```

Comment: this solution works very well, but what if there are other point in the file name? i.e. `file.name.ext`

Comment: @Luke yes it would work for those kind of inputs too. Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$ var=filename.ext
$ file.sh ${var%.*} ${var##*.}
```

- `${var%.*}` - deletes the shortest possible match `\.*` pattern from the right of variable `var`
- `${var##*.}` - deletes the longest possible match `*\.` pattern from the left of variable `var`

See [bash variables mangling](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue57/eyler.html) for details

Comment: This expands to `file.sh filename ext`, which is not what the OP wanted.